# filling the holes in a time series data

Tags: time, correlation, finance, series, stock

So i am trying to build one factor models with stocks and indices in R. I have 30 stocks and 16 indices in total. They are all time series from "2013-1-1" to "2014-12-31". Well at least all my stocks are. All of my indices are missing some entries here and there. For example, all of my stocks' data have the length of 522 but one indice has a length of 250, one 300, another 400 etc. But they all start from "2013-1-1" and end at "2014-12-31". Because my indice data has holes in it, i can't check correlations and build linear models with them. I can't do anything basically. So i need to fill these holes. I am thinking about filling those holes with their mean. But i don't know how to do it.I am open to other ideas of course. Can you help me? It is an important term project for me, so there is a lot on the line...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions like this which are not about programming are better served on another Stack Exchange site, such as [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the site for statistics. I have a feeling they'll recommend imputation.

Comment: i think it is about programming. isn't it? i am basically trying to fill holes in a time series without changing the existing dates.

Comment: Based on how the question is phrased, it appears you're asking for general methodological advice, which would be better from the statistical community, rather than programming advice. If you're looking for programming advice, please include the language you're using and examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Are you trying to do it with a specific language?  What have you tried already?

Comment: oh, my bad. I am trying to do this in R of course. The way i see it, i have 2 options: Trimming the stock data, which is almost impossible considering all my indices have holes in different entries, or filling the holes in indice data. I imagine i could fill it with its mean but i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edited based upon your comments (and to fix a mistake I made):

This is basic data management and I'm surprised that you're being required to work with timeseries data without knowing how to `merge()` and how to create dataframes.

Create some fake date and value data with holes in the dates:

```
    dFA <- data.frame(seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-02-28"), 3))
    names(dFA) <- "date"
    dFA$vals <- rnorm(nrow(dFA), 25, 5)
```

Create a dataframe of dates from the `min` value in dFA to the `max` value in dFA

```
    dFB <- as.data.frame(seq.Date(as.Date(min(dFA$date, na.rm = T), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                  as.Date(max(dFA$date, na.rm = T), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                  1))

    names(dFB) <- "date"
```

Merge the two dataframes together

```
    tmp <- merge(dFB, dFA, by = "date", all = T)
```

Change `NA` values in `tmp$vals` to whatever you want

```
    tmp$vals[is.na(tmp$vals)] <- mean(dFA$vals)
    head(tmp)
            date     vals
    1 2014-01-01 18.48131
    2 2014-01-02 24.16256
    3 2014-01-03 24.16256
    4 2014-01-04 28.78855
    5 2014-01-05 24.16256
    6 2014-01-06 24.16256
```

---

#### Original comment below

The easiest way to fill in the holes is with `merge()`.

Create a new data frame with one vector as a sequence of dates that span the range of your original dataframe and the other vector with whatever you're going to fill the holes (zeroes, means, whatever).  Then just `merge()` the two together:

```
    merge(dFB, dFA, by = [the column with the date values], all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Forgive me if i sound like a dumb person but i am new at this. How do i get the exact time sequence that my stock data has? Because my stock data has all the days, months and years in it. Do i have to extract it from one of my time series or can i build a new one?

Comment: i am so lost. the stock data that i have does not have weekends in it. and i just realized they are not in the form of time series. i imported them from YAHOO FINANCE. They just have the time information. That's all. Let's say i have a vector which contains a stock's closing prices between 2013-1-1 and 2014-12-31, without the weekends. Lets assume it is called x. And i have a vector which contains index data from 2013-1-1 to 2014-12-31 but it has gaps all around it. Let's call this one y. Length of x is 522 and y is say 350.

Comment: I want the index vector to be in a form where i can calculate its correlation with the stocks etc. I know i am asking too much here and you did not even have to write the explanation you did before but i would really really appreciate if you can explain to me how can i do this. Please assume you are talking to an idiot while you are explaning (if you would be so kind to do that of course)

Comment: The answer I gave above is written simply enough so that you can easily "fill in the holes" in your date vector.  What you update the blank values to is up to you.

As far as converting your data to a timeseries, see `ts()`.

I'm not interested in doing your term project for you, but if all you need is a correlation, look into `cor()`.

Comment: but in your example you use a straight up sequence with 7 days a week. i need to get rid of weekends days. is there a short way of doing that?

Comment: `?weekdays()`.  You need to add days of the week to a dataframe then remove the days that Saturday and Sunday.

  `tmp$days <- weekdays(tmp$date)
  daysToLose <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")
  tmp <- tmp[!(tmp$days %in% daysToLose), ]`

Really, you need to learn more about `R` before you dive into a project like this.